# 5 digit pairing code for Oculus Quest 2 totally not showing

Tags: oculus, oculusquest

I accidentally unpaired one of the hand controls for our Oculus Quest 2, and in order to re-pair it again, I need to connect the headset to the Oculus app in my phone. But when I try to do so, my phone app says it has no connection with my headset. When I click the headset on the first screen that comes up in the app, it says `Looking For Headset` for a few seconds, and then `Look into your headset for a 5-digit code and enter it here`.

[image: Look into your headset for a 5-digit code and enter it here. Oculus Quest 2]

But when I look into the headset, there is no such code showing! I once saw this code, during the original setup of the headset, but now, it doesn't come again. I only get into my lounge thingy direct.

I've tried changing user (there are two accounts in the headset) and restarting the headset, but no 5 digit code appears. I've also tried bluetooth-pairing it with the phone the normal way, and that succeeds but does not lead to a successful link between the headset and the app... I've looked in every menu for a secondary way to find this 5 digit code, but to no avail.

I've also talked with Meta Support, and funnily enough, they don't know either! They just said things like "The code should just be there when you look into the headset" and "I want you to try factory resetting your headset and see if that helps"... Well, I'd rather NOT factory reset my headset, thanks! Surely, there must be another way... Anybody in this competent community who knows better?

Comment: I'm having this same issue as well. Mobile app is asking for 5 digit but 5 digits aren't popping up in headset. The only thing I haven't tried yet is factory reset on the two devices I'm testing with. I think the phone is bound to a previous version of the Oculus OS and the pairing flow has a bug. I'd say we can't expect this bug to be resolved until the Quest predecessor is shipping.

Comment: So my answer below didn't help for you?

Comment: I'm not AirLinking as I'm on a Mac. 

Comment: Oh, ok... sorry about that. You should probably still try and stay on that "Swipe your pattern" screen in your Oculus, though! As that's where I was, when the phones suddenly said "pin automatically detected, swipe pattern to unlock Oculus"! Or try to borrow a PC if you can...  (It needs some 15 GB of free space, though.)

Comment: I assume you tried updating the phone's Oculus app?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally managed to solve the problem... without the 5 digit code!

This may seem weird, but I did it twice, with two different headsets, so it actually seems reproducible.

What I did was I downloaded the Oculus App for PC. (Not available for Mac.) In there, I set up an Airlink with the headset, like this:

1. PC and headset must be on the same WiFi
2. In the Oculus App on PC, click "Devices", choose your headset, and then "Connect via Airlink"
3. In the headset, go to Settings > System > Quest Link
4. Enable the Quest Link toggle switch
5. Launch Quest Link (Click the little square icon to the right of these words)
6. Enable the Air Link toggle switch

Now, the headset and my PC app connected. It would have been great if the hand controllers could be paired using the Oculus PC app... but they couldn't.

However, continue:

1. In your headset, click your profile pic (on the board below your TV)
2. Click "Switch Account". (If there's only one account in your headset, improvise this step!...)
3. Choose your account again (or a different one, whatever)
4. When you get to the place where you are supposed to enter your pattern to open your account, stop there. Look at your phone, which should still be on the screen shown in the qn. Don't let the headset go off! (You can achieve this by either keeping it on your head or covering the proximity sensor between the eyes in the headset with something.)

At this point, the phone Oculus App should say something like "Pairing code automatically detected", and then switch to another screen where you draw your pattern to unlock your headset Oculus account on your phone. It says "Draw your pattern to unlock headset" or something. I had to draw my pattern several times, because it was as if it lost connection in the middle of me drawing it, but after a few attempts, it went through, and the phone was now connected to the headset, and I could pair my hand controls!

It seems to me as if the phone is SUPPOSED to be able to detect this 5 digit code automatically so long as both headset and phone are logged in with the same account and bluetooth is on, but this just doesn't always happen. Then Airlink seems to help them find each other, somehow. I dunno.

Do tell me if this worked or didn't work for you, guys!